# Issue in JSON parser in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, parsing, sbjson

JSON Response like - {"response":{"Success":"Y","items":[{"userid":"255"}]}}

I tried to parse like this:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:mutaebleData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"JSonSTr : %@", jsonStr);
    
    SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON alloc]init];
    
    NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *) [json objectWithString:jsonStr];
    NSDictionary *dic1 = (NSDictionary *) [dic objectForKey:@"response"];
    NSDictionary *dic2 = (NSDictionary *) [dic1 objectForKey:@"Success"];
    NSDictionary *dic3 = (NSDictionary *) [dic1 objectForKey:@"items"];

    NSDictionary *dic4 = (NSDictionary *) [dic3 objectForKey:@"userid"]; // App crash in this line
}
```

How to get userid value?

Comment: From the error it seems dic3 is an array and not a dictionary. Can you  NSLog the class of dic3 and check.

Comment: Look at your JSON - the "items" key is associated with an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but please remove all those unsightly casts. They are usually not necessary in Objective-C and often just hide errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *) [json objectWithString:jsonStr];
 NSDictionary *dic1 = (NSDictionary *) [dic objectForKey:@"response"];
 NSDictionary *dic2 = (NSDictionary *) [dic1 objectForKey:@"Success"];
 NSDictionary *dic3 = (NSDictionary *) [dic1 objectForKey:@"items"];
    
 for(NSDictionary *str in dic3)
 {
    NSLog(@"str:%@",[str valueForKey:@"userid"]);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
 NSDictionary *dic4 = (NSDictionary *) [dic3 objectForKey:@"userid"];
```

You should use:

```
NSDictionary *dic4 = (NSDictionary *) [[dic3 objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"userid"];
```

Comment: The real problem is `NSDictionary *dic3 = (NSDictionary *) [dic1 objectForKey:@"items"];` since the "items" key is mapped to an array. It should be `NSArray *items = (NSArray *)[dic1 objectForKey:@"items"];`.

Comment: i tried this but the error comes in "No visible @interface for nsdictionary declare the selector objectatindex"

Comment: Change this:
 NSDictionary *dic3 = (NSDictionary *) [dic1 objectForKey:@"items"];
into:
 NSArray *dic3 = (NSArray *) [dic1 objectForKey:@"items"];

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:mutaebleData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"JSonSTr : %@", jsonStr);

SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON alloc]init];

NSDictionary *dic = (NSDictionary *) [json objectWithString:jsonStr];
NSDictionary *dic1 = (NSDictionary *) [dic objectForKey:@"response"];
NSDictionary *dic2 = (NSDictionary *) [dic1 objectForKey:@"Success"];
NSArray *arr3 = (NSArray *) [dic1 objectForKey:@"items"];

NSString *str = [[arr objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"userid"];
NSlog(@"userid ==%@",str);
// NSDictionary *dic4 = (NSDictionary *) [dic3 objectForKey:@"userid"]; // App crash in this line
 }
```

Comment: i tried this but the error comes in nslog - Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_NSlog", referenced from:

Comment: Instead of NSlog type NSLog....It will solve ur pblm and do accept the answer is it's correct

Comment: I got the answer, please see above

Answer (score 0):

You can add SBJSON framework files. and By parsing the by

```
NSDictionary *responseDict = [response JSONValue];
just parse it as normal dictionary.

NSString *userIDValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[responseDict valueForKey:@"response"]valueForKey:@"items"]objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"userid"]];
```